# Why APIClient return empty data response Django RF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm traying to make some tests for an api here is the code:

tests.py

```
class APITest(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.api_client = APIClient()

    def test_get_lists(self):
        response = self.api_client.get('/api/t/')
        print(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)


    def test_post_list(self):
        response = self.api_client.post('/api/t/',
                                data={'user':1, 'title':'AAA'})
        print(response.data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

viewset.py

```
class TableViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Table.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TableSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class TableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lists = ListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Table
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'title', 'id', 'timestamp', 'lists')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        table = Table.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return table

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        return instance
```

when I want to print the response data in test.py, I get an empty array and an OK test
the response content:

```
Response status_code=200, "application/json"
```

Comment: Did you create any items in your test case?

Comment: no, I create items from admin and try to get them

Comment: But tests always start from an empty database. If you want to fetch items in a test, you need to create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution was to create model in the test, because we can't use the models from db when we do tests